# run stackblitz typescript project locally

Tags: typescript, stackblitz

I create a starter typescript project in stackblitz

index.html does not import any js or css but it works in their preview window.

How do I run this project locally? Seems like I would have to modify index.html to include js and css?

How do they preview it in stackblitz without the js and css included in index.html?